# Stretching table

Tags: tables, macros

I defined a custom command to produce a table I have to do for various experiments:

```
\newcommand{\exptable}[3]{
\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline 
        Particle & Voltage & Flow rate \\ 
        \hline 
        #1&\SI{#2}{\volt}&\SI{#3}{\micro\liter\per\minute}  \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
}
```

This works great but the tables have different widths for different inputs. I would like to change it so that it has a minimum width larger than my inputs so it always has the same width (for example 7cm or something I can set).

Comment: You can simply change the `c` column type in the table preamble  to   `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{some width}`.

Comment: Please make your code snippet -- as always here -- compilable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\exptable}[4]{%
\begin{center}
    \sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{C{#4}}}
    \hline 
    Particle & Voltage & Flow rate \\ 
    \hline 
    #1&\SI{#2}{\volt}&\SI{#3}{\micro\liter\per\minute}  \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}        
\exptable{Stuff}{4.5}{1.2345}{3cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Is it possible to have some space in the beginning of the table? (i.e. before the P of "Particle" and S of "Stuff")

Comment: @Superuser27 - Sure! Just remove the `@{}` particle in `\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{C{#4}}}`.

Comment: Off topic: why did you add `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}` ? Personal preference? `:)`

Comment: @Superuser27 - You got me pegged. :-) To my eyes `L/min` looks a tad more pleasing than `L min^{-1}` does...